# UK Visitor Visa for PLAB exam expiring and exams cancelled due to COVID

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, covid-19, visa-expiration

I'm currently in my home country. I applied for the visit visa in February and was granted a six month visit visa. I was planning to travel in third week of March for the exam when things locked down and exams got cancelled. I applied for another date in first week of August, but that was cancelled, too. My visa expires in 2nd week of August but the exams will resume in September or October.

What are my options now apart from letting the visa expire and applying again? I was rejected once before and my PLAB 1 expires in November.

Comment: Clearly you will need a new visa. Your options, then, are to travel when exams resume, remembering that the UK has just introduced a 14 day quarantine scheme, or wait until the travel situation eases which might necessitate taking PLAB 1 again. On that, only you can decide. Obviously you would only apply for a new visa once you have decided your new plans.

Answer (score 0):

Apply for a new visa.

UK Immigration is well aware of the current situation and the difficulties that imposes on international travel - your current visa was issued with a specific intent in mind, and that intent was prevented by the pandemic.

Your previous denial is not an issue as you have been successful since then (if I am interpreting your question correctly).  The fact that you have not travelled during the period of the pandemic will not count as a negative, nor will the fact that the visa expired unused during this time - UK Immigration is well aware at the best of times that plans change, and recent events have certainly caused plans to change.

Apply for a new visa, be open and honest when asked about why you are applying - if given the opportunity to explain, do so.